# Pushing List Tile Leading Down in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this very simple List Tile, but I would like to push the leading icon (in this case an image) down, I have tried adding padding to Container, but it doesn't move it at all. Here's the code:

```
ListTile(
  isThreeLine: true,
  leading: Container(
  height: double.infinity,

  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.01,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
   image: DecorationImage(
    image: food.image != null
        ? Utility
        .imageFromBase64String(
         food.image)
         : MemoryImage(
             kTransparentImage),
               fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,)), ),
```

Something like this, first example is how it looks now, second how I would want it to. As I said, I have tried adding padding in the container, but it doesn't work, almost as if List Tile has a fixed height.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Transform` to move the `leading` widget around.

I wrote an example.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.identity()..translate(0.0, 10.0)..scale(1.5),
            child: Icon(Icons.person),
          ),
          title: Text("Title"),
          subtitle: Text("Subtitle" * 20),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you ,very much appreciated. I'm learning some widgets I never knew existed!